# Is there anything wrong with this definition of discontinuity?

Tags: analysis, definition, epsilon-delta

Is there anything wrong with this definition of discontinuity for a function y = f(x)?

$\forall \delta>0\, \exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $\vert x-c\vert < \delta$, but $\vert f(x) - f(c)\vert > \epsilon$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: Discontinuity $\implies $ your assertion, but the converse is wrong. That's why it can't work as a definition of discontinuity.

Comment: What is $ c $? What is $ x $?

Comment: This is actually a definition of not being locally constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take the usual definition of continuity and negate it, you get
$$
\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists c\in \mathbb{R}:     |x - c| < \delta \text{ and } |f(x) - f(c)| > \epsilon.
$$
Your definition is missing quantification on $c$, but more importantly, you've switched the orders of the quantifiers on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, which is not legitimate. As explained in the comments, with the quantifiers reversed, your definition is implied by but does not imply discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:  the answer below is incorrect, but I'm leaving it up to show the possible pitfalls of alternative approaches.**  If time allows, I'll try to refine and correct it at a later date.

---

It's almost true;  it needs a slight refinement:

> $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x$ when $\forall \delta > 0, \exists \epsilon > 0$ such that **for all $x$ satisfying** $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, $|f(x) - f(c)| > \epsilon$.

Without the "for all" I've bolded above, it doesn't work. For example, take $f(x) = x$ and $c = 0$.  For a given $\delta > 0$, choose $\epsilon = \delta/2$.  Then for at least some $x$ such that $|x| < \delta$, $|f(x)| = x \ngtr \epsilon = \delta /2$.

Comment: Two problems: (i) you need "for all $x\ne c$" or your definition is never satisfied, and (ii) a function continuous only on one side still fails to satisfy your definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment — I addressed it by demanding that $0 < |x - c|$ as well.  As far as the other comment goes — is it customary to require that a function not be continuous on either side of a point to be considered discontinuous at that point?  I would have thought, for example, that the function $f(x) = x$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = x + 1$ for $ x \geq 0$ was a discontinuous function.  (Certainly it wouldn't be continuous under the topological definition of continuity.)

Comment: That's a discontinuous function, of course, the problem is that it doesn't satisfy your definition of discontinuity. That is, it *fails to be discontinuous* under your definition.

Comment: @Rahul:  Ah, I see your point.  I'll have to think about how to salvage this definition (or if it is easily salvageable.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one negation for the definition of continuity

$\exists \varepsilon>0:\nexists\delta>0$ for which $|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\varepsilon$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640641/is-there-anything-wrong-with-this-definition-of-discontinuity#comment3345765_1640641)

> This is actually a definition of not being locally constant. – Rahul  Feb 4 at 17:49

The proposed definition

$\forall \delta>0\, \exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $\vert x-c\vert < \delta$, but $\vert f(x) - f(c)\vert > \epsilon$

is equivalent to

$\forall \delta>0\, \exists c$ such that $\vert x-c\vert < \delta$, but $f(x) \neq f(c)$,

which is the statement that the function is non-constant on arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $x$.  Requiring the same condition for all $x$ is the statement that the function is not locally constant near any point.